# Xamarin.forms: How to get Object value from a Listview

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am placing a stepper inside a Listview. I would like to know which Item the Stepper belong to when I change it.
Here is the Listview. I would like to know, when I modify the stepper's value, which EAN is part of the same ViewCell.

```
        <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            HasUnevenRows="true"
            RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}"
            IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
            IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
            ItemTapped="OnItemSelected"
              >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="10" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"  FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  />
                            <Label Text="{Binding QuantityExpectedDisplay}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"  FontSize="10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  />
                            <Label Text="{Binding EAN}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"  FontSize="10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  />
                            <Stepper Value="{Binding QuantityDefect}" Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding Quantity}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ValueChanged="Stepper_ValueChanged" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

So that I can use that ean later to find the corresponding line. (In the example, I would like to find the ListItem, or at least its EAN in test, rather than putting a new one)

```
    private void Stepper_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListItem test = new ListItem();//Here I'd like the ViewCell Values
        var line = viewModel.lines.Find(l => l.Ean == test.EAN);
        line.QuantityOpen = (int)e.NewValue;
    }
```

Thank you and have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

We generally don't recommend using this method，you can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your the item of `Items`.

Suppose the item model is `Item.cs`, you can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as follows:

```
public class Item: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string QuantityExpectedDisplay{ get; set; }
    public string EAN{ get; set; }

    //public int  QuantityDefect { get; set; }

    int _quantityDefect;
    public int QuantityDefect
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref _quantityDefect, value); }

        get { return _quantityDefect; }
    }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

And in `YourPage.xaml`,we can do like this:

```
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Padding="10" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"  FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  />
                        <Label Text="{Binding QuantityExpectedDisplay}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"  FontSize="10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  />
                        <Label Text="{Binding EAN}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"  FontSize="10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  />
                        <Stepper Value="{Binding QuantityDefect}" Minimum="0" Maximum="10" Increment="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Note:

Once we change  the stepper's value,  the value of `QuantityDefect`  will change accordingly.

**Update**

> How can I find more information about this type of binding? How is it
> called, so I can find out how it works for later?

Yes, if we implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for Item and  change the value, it also change the value of the `ItemsSource` of current listview.

For example,, suppose the view model of current page is `MyViewModel.cs`:

```
    public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> items { get; set; }
    public MyViewModel() {
        items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        items.Add(new Item { Name = "Tomato", Quantity = 100, QuantityDefect = 10 });
        items.Add(new Item { Name = "Romaine Lettuce",  Quantity = 100, QuantityDefect = 10 });
        items.Add(new Item { Name = "Zucchini", Quantity = 100, QuantityDefect = 10 });

    }
}
```

Then we can also get the modified `ItemsSource` as follows(I added a Button to print the data):

```
public partial class MainViewXaml : ContentPage
{

    MyViewModel viewModel;
    public MainViewXaml ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        viewModel = new MyViewModel();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }

    private void Stepper_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    // we can get the items here
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Item item in viewModel.items) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" name : " + item.Name + "<-----> QuantityDefect = " + item.QuantityDefect);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried to implement your solution, but failed. I'm not used to working with so much property handling. If I understand properly, when I change the value, it should also change the value in the other object?

Basically, in the viewmodel there is the list of lines and the list of items. Items is just a standardized type for the views.


        public List<ReturnLine> lines;
        public ObservableCollection<ListItem> Items { get; set; }

How can I find more information about this type of binding? How is it called, so I can find out how it works for later? Thank you

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm

Comment: Hi @Elgate, I don't know what specific function you want to implement. But you  can check my updated answer at the bottom of my reply.

Answer (score 0):

First, see Jessie's answer for the basics of Data Binding to a list of items.

Or see example described in [ListView Data Sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding).

---

In addition, we need a way to tell viewmodel what item has changed.

MessagingCenter can do this.

MyViewModel.cs:

```cs
public MyViewModel()
{
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MyItem>(this, "changed", Item_Changed);
}

public ObservableCollection<MyItem> Items { get; set; }

private void Item_Changed(MyItem item)
{
    var index = Items.IndexOf(item);
    // Make sure it is mine.
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

MyItem.cs:

```cs
int _quantityDefect;
public int QuantityDefect
{
    get => _quantityDefect;
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _quantityDefect, value);
        Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send<MyItem>(this, "changed");
    }
}
```